# how to add a field for choose a directory in django model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I need a field to specify the path of my backup file and I write this model:

```
def backup_path():
    return os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR.parent, "backups")


class Backup(Authorable, Publishable, models.Model):
    file_path = models.FilePathField(
        _("مسیر فایل"),
        path=backup_path,
        recursive=True,
    )
    file_size = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("حجم فایل"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("تهیه پشتیبان")
        verbose_name_plural = _("تهیه پشتیبان")
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.file_path} - {self.file_size}"
    
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        BackupService.run(self.file_path)
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

but in admin panel I can't choose a directory for save backup file.

how can i choose a directory in admin?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the issue and find a way to let you choose a directory for saving the backup file in the admin panel.

First, we should change the `models.FilePathField` to a `models.CharField`. This is because the `FilePathField` is designed to let you choose a file, not a directory. By using `CharField`, you can manually input the directory path for the backup file.

Here's the updated code for your `Backup` model:

```py
class Backup(Authorable, Publishable, models.Model):
    file_path = models.CharField(
        _("مسیر فایل"),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    file_size = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("حجم فایل"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    # Rest of the code
```

Now, you'll be able to enter the directory path in the admin panel as a text input.

Comment: Isn't there a way to choose a directory instead of entering the path manually?

Comment: Use a third-party Django package called django-admin-file-selector, which allows you to select directories from the Django admin interface.